# WxPython - How to hide the X and expand button on window

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, wxpython

Im making a python program and in some functions it needs to hide the X and expand window buttons, how would i do it? Im using WxPython, how would I put this in?

Comment: Do you want to have a normal frame, and hide the close and zoom buttons programmatically, or do you just want to be able to create frames that don't have those buttons? (The second one is easier—and may make more sense cross-platform, too.)

Comment: @abarnet I want to be able to create frams that dont havethose buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote about Frame styles a while ago on my [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/11/06/wxpython-101-using-frame-styles/). To remove all the buttons, you could do this:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class NoSystemMenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    There is no system menu, which means the title bar is there, but
    no buttons and no menu when clicking the top left hand corner
    of the frame
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        no_sys_menu = wx.CAPTION
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="No System Menu", style=no_sys_menu)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = NoSystemMenuFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I tried setting the style to `wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & (~wx.CLOSE_BOX) & (~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)` and to `wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE^(wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)`, but both of those seem to only remove the Close box. For some reason, the Maximize button is still there on my Xubuntu machine.

Comment: On Xubuntu, the maximize widget may not be controlled by `MAXIMIZE_BOX`. The way `wx` tries to map each platform's native widgets to its Windows-inspired generic widgets isn't always what you'd expect. The documentation for how that mapping is done is buried somewhere in the wxWidgets (C++) API, not directly available from the wxPython docs, but you can search for it pretty easily, or just experiment with the different style flags to see which one does what.

Comment: Yeah, I've played around with the styles quite a bit over the years, but I was under the impression that wx was made so that it did map across platforms better than this.

Comment: They do the best they can to make their design work cross-platform, but some things are just impossible on some platforms (e.g., showing `SYSTEM_MENU` without `CAPTION` on Mac), and others are very hard (e.g., controlling `MAXIMIZE_BOX` on Motif without MHM enabled), or just ugly or nonstandard for the platform (which is why `MINIMIZE_BOX` gives you disabled instead of absent `CLOSE_BOX` and `MAXIMIZE_BOX` on Mac). I don't know the details of how each frame maps to each platform, but I do know there are issues that they can't easily solve.

Comment: If I had to guess, the problem in this case may be that removing `MAXIMIZE_BOX` while leaving `MINIMIZE_BOX` can't be cleanly represented in Gtk+, so they worked out what was the least-bad thing to do with that combination of styles and did it.

Comment: I asked Robin Dunn about this and he said that some platforms will impose limits on what can and cannot be removed. This is especially true on Linux because it has policies for different window managers. So Mr. Dunn said that wx basically just "hints" to the platform that it should do something, but the platform can ignore the hint.

Answer (score 6):

The widgets in the window frame are defined as part of the window's style: `CLOSE_BOX`, `MINIMIZE_BOX`, and `MAXIMIZE_BOX`.

So, when you create the window, just leave those styles out.

If you're using a `wx.Frame` subclass, note that [`DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_frame.html) includes these values, so you will have to mask them out:

```
style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & (~wx.CLOSE_BOX) & (~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
super().__init__(whatever, args, you, use, style=style)
```

---

If you want to change them after creation, you use [`SetWindowStyle`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetWindowStyle):

```
style = self.GetWindowStyle()
self.SetWindowStyle(style & (~wx.CLOSE_BOX) & (~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
self.Refresh()
```

However, notice that the documentation of that function says:

> Please note that some styles cannot be changed after the window creation and that Refresh() might need to be called after changing the others for the change to take place immediately.

And, from what I can tell, on Windows, if you create a window with a close box and then remove it later in this way, it doesn't actually go away. It does disable, which may be good enough. But if not, there's probably no way to do what you want without either reaching underneath `wx` to the native Windows API (which gets very tricky), or drawing the widgets on the frame manually (which gets even more tricky, especially if you care about looking right on different versions of Windows—not to mention porting to other platforms).

Comment: I get the error " TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)" when using this method

Comment: @saberman888: You don't literally want to put `(whatever, args, you, use, style=style)` there; however you're currently initializing your windows, add or replace the `style` argument appropriately. Since you never showed your code, nobody can show you how to do that for your code, but it should be pretty obvious.

Comment: You could actually save some operations and making the flag-setting more clear by using xor `wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE^(wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)`.

Comment: @nepix32: I think that's actually less clear, because `^` just toggles the bits—to understand whether it's setting them or clearing them, you have to go look up what the original values were—while `& ~` explicitly clears them. (But if you're happy using the toggling, for the dynamic case, you can use `ToggleWindowStyle` and not do any bit operations directly at all.)

Comment: @abanert: +1 for pointing out `ToggleWindowStyle`, was not aware of that (or did already forget it).